# how to give two words as input(morse code) and become two words but between them space

Tags: python-3.x, morse-code

```
CODE = {'A': '.-',     'B': '-...',   'C': '-.-.', 
        'D': '-..',    'E': '.',      'F': '..-.',
        'G': '--.',    'H': '....',   'I': '..',
        'J': '.---',   'K': '-.-',    'L': '.-..',
        'M': '--',     'N': '-.',     'O': '---',
        'P': '.--.',   'Q': '--.-',   'R': '.-.',
        'S': '...',    'T': '-',      'U': '..-',
        'V': '...-',   'W': '.--',    'X': '-..-',
        'Y': '-.--',   'Z': '--..',

        '0': '-----',  '1': '.----',  '2': '..---',
        '3': '...--',  '4': '....-',  '5': '.....',
        '6': '-....',  '7': '--...',  '8': '---..',
        '9': '----.' 
        }

CODE_REVERSED = {value:key for key,value in CODE.items()}

def from_morse(s):
    return ''.join(CODE_REVERSED.get(i) for i in s.split())
```

I want to give two words and become two words and between them space!!
for example something like that: 
.... . .-.. .-.. ---   .-- --- .-. -..
HELLO WORLD not **HELLOWORLD**

```
>>> from_morse('.... . .-.. .-.. ---') 
'HELLO'
```

Comment: add the key value pair for space in your CODE dictionary

Comment: I wrote "  ":"  " but it is still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dictionary should include space too:

```
CODE = {'A': '.-',     'B': '-...',   'C': '-.-.', 
        'D': '-..',    'E': '.',      'F': '..-.',
        'G': '--.',    'H': '....',   'I': '..',
        'J': '.---',   'K': '-.-',    'L': '.-..',
        'M': '--',     'N': '-.',     'O': '---',
        'P': '.--.',   'Q': '--.-',   'R': '.-.',
        'S': '...',    'T': '-',      'U': '..-',
        'V': '...-',   'W': '.--',    'X': '-..-',
        'Y': '-.--',   'Z': '--..',

        '0': '-----',  '1': '.----',  '2': '..---',
        '3': '...--',  '4': '....-',  '5': '.....',
        '6': '-....',  '7': '--...',  '8': '---..',
        '9': '----.',  ' ': '/'  # <--- the '/' is used for space
        }
```

So, for :

```
from_morse('.... . .-.. .-.. --- / .-- --- .-. .-.. -..')
```

it gives:

```
'HELLO WORLD'
```

---

if you dont want to use '/':

```
CODE = {'A': '.-',     'B': '-...',   'C': '-.-.', 
        'D': '-..',    'E': '.',      'F': '..-.',
        'G': '--.',    'H': '....',   'I': '..',
        'J': '.---',   'K': '-.-',    'L': '.-..',
        'M': '--',     'N': '-.',     'O': '---',
        'P': '.--.',   'Q': '--.-',   'R': '.-.',
        'S': '...',    'T': '-',      'U': '..-',
        'V': '...-',   'W': '.--',    'X': '-..-',
        'Y': '-.--',   'Z': '--..',

        '0': '-----',  '1': '.----',  '2': '..---',
        '3': '...--',  '4': '....-',  '5': '.....',
        '6': '-....',  '7': '--...',  '8': '---..',
        '9': '----.',  ' ': ''  
        }
def from_morse(s):
    return ''.join(CODE_REVERSED.get(i) for i in s.split(' '))
```

then give:

```
from_morse('.... . .-.. .-.. ---  .-- --- .-. .-.. -..')
```

So here, were ever you need space, leave 2 spaces, one for spliting and one for the real space.